# Creating ASP.NET MVC4 project to connect to SiteCore Master for Admin Access

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, sitecore, sitecore6

I have a SiteCore 6.5 already installed, and I just want to create a simple ASP.NET MVC4 application that will connect to the Sitecore\Admin, and allow me to call Context.GetItem("/sitecore/content/home") function call. Is there an easy of doing this? What do I have to change in the web.config to make this happen? This is used as a simple Admin toolbox app, so all of the username and password are hardcoded for the connection, and I am just using the SecurityDisabler() and UserSwithcher() to run the function under Admin.

Comment: Have you looked at Sitecore 6.6 which has MVC support out of the box?

Comment: No. I don't think that's an option. The project is already built in 6.5 and they don't want to risk the upgrade to break compatibility. the Admin toolbox MVC4 project doesn't do anything fancy, it will just update some static class in the middle layer project that does SiteCore implementations. I just want to give the Admin a nice way of changing that, otherwise, I can just update it in code per build.

Comment: Have you read through this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10012619/sitecore-6-5-with-mvc3

Comment: thanks for the help. yeah, I had seen that, but what he is accomplishing is different than what I was looking for. thank you though.

Comment: Even though I did this for a Sitecore 6.6 it may be that the same changes can be applied to get a 6.5 to coexist with a MVC4 application: http://herskind.co.uk/blog/2012/10/sitecore-66-mvc4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to connect a MVC 4 app to the Sitecore 6.5 installation for some admin implementations. I just copied the entire folder for App_Config and Web.Config file to the MVC app, and the start to migrate the MVC4 web.config into the copied web.config from the installations. I then started to take out pieces one at a time, most of the part that you should take out will show up in the as error when you run the application, but the main part that we giving me an error was the httpredirection to the sitecore installation, and that was the httphandlers tag and httpModules tag, and my MVC app showed right now, and I was able to connect to the Sitecore configuration and factory.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the Sitecore Item Web API module, it's available on the [SDN](http://sdn.sitecore.net/SDN5/Products/Sitecore%20Item%20Web%20API/SitecoreItemWebApi10.aspx). The API gives access to content through items paths, IDs, and Sitecore queries.

The Item Web API was the subject of a presentation at this month's London User Group meeting. You can find a recording of the presentation on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=muLFkTlYtCM) and the demo code is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/herskinduk/Usergroup.ItemWebApi).

If you want to understand what is required to use the standard Sitecore API's to access content items outside of the website context Mike Edwards has a great post on [How to configure Sitecore 6.5 to work in NUnit](http://www.experimentsincode.com/?p=343). This post explains what configuration will be required in the caller to access Sitecore without a context and it will then be possible to execute code like the following:

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using Sitecore.Data;
using Sitecore.Data.Items;

[TestFixture]
public class when_connecting_to_sitecore_master_database
{
    [Test]
    public void it_can_retrieve_the_root_item()
    {
        Database db = global::Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("master");
        Item item = db.GetItem("/sitecore");
        Assert.IsNotNull(item);
        Assert.AreEqual("sitecore", item.Name.ToLower());
    }
}
```

Comment: This sounds very interesting! I got the problem resolved, but this seems to make it a little easier next time.