# What is the XML format for an item for the Sitecore Webservice

Tags: web-services, sitecore

I am trying to use the built in web service in Sitecore 6.5 (.../sitecore/shell/webservice/service.asmx)

There is [PDF](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/65/Sitecore_Web_Service_SC65_A4.pdf) that describes the commands, but it does not specify the format for inserting/updating items. It claims one can simply use the format when doing a GetXml request, but I have found that not to be true from my testing.

I have tried a number of variations, both trying with an  or just single fields as suggested by this [blog](http://blog.hansmelis.be/2012/05/29/sitecore-web-service-pitfalls/), with no luck and unfortunately the webservice does not complain about the input, it always responds "OK" with no effect.

The full request (as what I am looking at now)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope
  xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

<soapenv:Body>
    <Save xmlns="http://sitecore.net/visual/">
              <xml>
     &lt;sitecore&gt;
        &lt;field   itemid=&quot;{7CCE4419-E8BD-45F4-9B9C-625E220C59A1}&quot;
                fieldid=&quot;{3F4B20E9-36E6-4D45-A423-C86567373F82}&quot; 
                language=&quot;en&quot;
                version=&quot;1&quot;&gt;
            &lt;content&gt;A title from service&lt;/content&gt;
        &lt;/field&gt;
     &lt;/sitecore&gt;
    </xml>
        <databaseName>master</databaseName>
        <credentials><!-- removed --></credentials>
    </Save>
</soapenv:Body>
```

If anyone knows what the format is that would be great.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Sitecore 6.5 then you can use the [Item Web API](http://sdn.sitecore.net/SDN5/Products/Sitecore%20Item%20Web%20API/SitecoreItemWebApi10.aspx), this should give you access to everything you need via JSON REST services.

There was a great response from [Kevin Obee with further links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14760623/creating-asp-net-mvc4-project-to-connect-to-sitecore-master-for-admin-access#answer-14798728), but also have a read of the following:

- [Sitecore Item Web API and Json.Net Test Drive](http://weblogs.asp.net/jonelrienton/archive/2012/11/08/sitecore-item-web-api-and-json-net-test-drive.aspx)
- [New features in Sitecore 6.6 – Webinar](http://larre.fixstar.net/category/cms/sitecore/item-web-api/)

Comment: It sounds very promising, but I cannot access the "Item Web API" link even with a Sitecore SDN account, I tried browsing the "Documentation" section, but it does not look like it is publicly available.

Comment: Just tried it and works fine for me... SDN > Products > Sitecore Item Web API. It's just a PDF: http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sdn5/modules/sitecore%20item%20web%20api/sitecore_item_web_api_developer_guide_sc65-66-usletter.pdf Perhaps contact Sitecore

Comment: Thank you, I can get the PDF from that link, and even though not what I was looking for originally, this looks like a great alternative and documentation is better than what Sitecore have for the SOAP web service.

Comment: It's new in 6.5 so personally I would use this going forward rather than rolling your own if possible :) Glad it is of help.

Answer (score 1):

I normally write my own webservice if I want to do some modifications to Sitecore items and found it a much more flexible way because I mostly want at least just a bit more functionality then the standard webservice has to offer. But be aware that you cannot serialize the Sitecore.Data.Items.Item class so sending an Item object through Soap is not going to work.

Comment: Yes, but I really don't want to write a custom web service. I am in a  environment where I can just consume the web service as-is. The more I search online, it appears the builtin webservice is more of a checkbox feature on a datasheet rather than intended for actual use.